# Weak solution of p-laplacian is a minimizer for its energy functional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, p-laplacian

I'm trying to show that for a weak solution of the p-laplacian dirichlet problem, that is, for $u \in W^{1.p}_0 (\Omega)$ s.t.
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v  = \int_\Omega f v \  \text{, }  \forall v \in W^{1.p}_0 (\Omega)
$$
then $u$ minimizes the energy functional associated
$$
\Phi(u) = \int_\Omega \frac{|\nabla u|^p}{p} - fu
$$

The other direction, that is, showing that $\Phi^\prime (u)(v) = 0$, was ok to do, so i know that $u$ is a critical point, but i don't know to show that is indeed a minimum point.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the minimization is easily attainable once one has the following inequality

$$
|b|^p \geq |a|^p + p<|a|^{p-2}a,b-a>
$$

as shown in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4284429/304381).

Then, taking $b=\nabla v$ and $a = \nabla u$, and therefore

$$
\frac{1}{p}|\nabla v|^p \geq \frac{1}{p}|\nabla u|^p + <|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u,\nabla (v-u)>
$$

so integrating both sides yields

$$
\frac{1}{p} \int |\nabla v|^p \geq  \frac{1}{p} \int|\nabla u|^p + \int |\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot\nabla (v-u)
$$
as $v-u \in W_0^{1,p}$ and $u$ is a weak solution

$$
\int |\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u \cdot\nabla (v-u) = \int f(v-u)
$$

then it follows that

$$
\frac{1}{p} \int |\nabla v|^p - \int fv \geq \frac{1}{p} \int|\nabla u|^p -\int fu
$$

as desired.